# Video relations not working for tx_news on TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I have been developing a site with TYPO3 6.2.15 and using the extension tx_news to show, well, news. Setting "Use FAL relations instead of news media elements" to "FAL + Multimedia" I could create relations with YouTube files, and they were shown in the frontend, both detail and list (if they have "Show in preview views" checked) page. The problem now is that after updating to TYPO3 7.6.2 they don't show up anymore. Gone, they appear in the backend if you edit a news record, but not in the frontend.

I know, in the documentation it says that the integration of audio and video is still to be done:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/stable/singlehtml/#video-audio-file

but it worked with TYPO3 6.2, so I assume it should work too with 7.6 too. The tx_news version I am using is 4.0.0.

Has anybody had the same issue and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The CE media element was removed in TYPO3 7LTS. In order to keep the old behaviour there is a system extension "mediace". I would install and configure it (f.e. add the static typoscript).

Comment: Actually, I solved it by modifying the partial MediaVideo.html file:

`code`<div class="videoobjectwrap"><object class="videoobject" data="{mediaElement.multimedia}"></object></div>`code`

A bit dirty, but it simply works.

Answer (score 0):

The custom media rendering has been removed in the master (upcoming 5.0.0) in favor of FAL. The best solution is to use

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.falMedia}" as="mediaElement">
  <f:media file="{mediaElement}" class="img-responsive" />
</:for>
```

as this uses the renderers of FAL which can be of course also be extended by custom solutions.